# Is there an odd integer $x < 105$ for which it is known that $x \nmid N$, if $N$ is an odd perfect number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-numbers

Is there an odd integer $x < 105$ for which it is known that $x \nmid N$, if $N$ is an odd perfect number?

I have asked the same question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882559), but did not get any answers.  I was wondering if anybody here has anything to share regarding this.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you include 105 in your range?

Comment: That is exactly the point, @WlodzimierzHolsztynski.  We already know that $105 \nmid N$ (see e.g., [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236891)), where $N$ is an odd perfect number.  What I am interested to know about would be:  Is there an *odd* integer $x$ smaller than $105$ for which it is *known* that $x \nmid N$?

Comment: Note that $105 = 3\cdot5\cdot7$.  I guess another way to ask my question would be: Is there any special reason why, if $x$ is an odd integer satisfying $x \nmid N$ where $N$ is an odd perfect number, it seems that $\omega(x) \geq 3$, where $\omega(x)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $x$?  (See e.g., [MSE1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768975), [MSE2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388734), and [MSE3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400579).)

Comment: J.A.D., thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, such a result would be a major breakthrough regarding our knowledge on odd perfect numbers.

A few years ago there was some confusion, since due to careless reading and citing of the article "Every odd perfect number has a prime factor which exceeds $10^6$" by Cohen and Hagis the impression arose that they had proved just such a theorem (which they never claimed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Pu.  I guess what Cohen and Hagis really proved is that the *largest* prime factor of an odd perfect number exceeds ${10}^6$?

Comment: Additionally, can you comment more on why you say that "such a result would be a major breakthrough regarding our knowledge on odd perfect numbers"?

Comment: Cohen and Hagis proved that the largest prime factor of an odd perfect number is $>10^6$. Of course, the proof is indirect, so it begins with "Let $n$ be an odd perfect number with all prime divisors $\leq 10^6$...". Then a sequence of properties for $n$ are deduced, one of which reads "Lemma: $n$ is not divisible by 3, 5, 7, ..." . This Lemma was later taken out of context and cited as "Let $n$ be an odd perfect number. Then $n$ is not divisible by 3,5,7,...".

Comment: There is a lot of literature proving the non-existence of odd perfect numbers satisfying certain additional restrictions. Practically all of them require some starting point of the form "One of these primes divides $n$" or "One of these primes does not divide $n$". Sometimes this starting point is easy to get (e.g. if you bound the number of distinct prime factors), but quite often getting the starting point is the most difficult part.

Comment: For example, McDaniel (On the divisibility of an odd perfect number by the sixth power of a prime.
Math. Comp. 25 (1971), 383–385) showed that an odd perfect number is either divisible by the sixth power of a prime, or it is not divisible by any prime $<100$. The proof is quite easy, once one has shown that if $n$ is not divisible by the sixth power of a prime, then $n$ is not divisible by some small prime, but getting there is pretty difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comments @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Fletcher, Nielsen and Ochem have a relatively recent [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2011-02576-7/home.html) where they show, using a new factor chain argument, that $5$ does not divide an odd perfect number indivisible by a sixth power.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to be posted as a comment, as I just wanted to share some of my recent thoughts on why it is difficult to obtain such an integer $x \nmid N$, where $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is a (hypothetical) odd perfect number.

Since a multiple of an abundant number is also abundant, and since the smallest odd abundant number is $945$, we know that
$${3^3}\cdot{5}\cdot{7} = 945 \nmid N.$$
In fact, we know that
$$3\cdot5\cdot7 = 105 \nmid N,$$
although $105$ is deficient.

Note that
$$\{\{3 \mid N\} \land \{5 \mid N\} \land \{7 \mid N\}\} \implies \{105 \mid N\}.$$
By the contrapositive,
$$\{105 \nmid N\} \implies \{\{3 \nmid N\} \lor \{5 \nmid N\} \lor \{7 \nmid N\}\}.$$

However, all existing computational projects which implement factor chains (see this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298509) for a very down-to-earth sample) to check whether $3 \mid N$ or otherwise have not terminated (i.e., AKA "resulted to a contradiction").  Likewise, it is currently unknown whether the smallest possible Euler prime $q = 5$ does divide an odd perfect number.  (<s>It is known though, by work of [Iannucci](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000-69-230/S0025-5718-99-01127-8/S0025-5718-99-01127-8.pdf), that $q = 5$ implies $k = \nu_{q}(N) = 1$.</s> Iannucci proved that $q = 5$ implies $k = \nu_{q}(N) = 1$ under some additional assumptions.)